# How to move cursor automatically from editor to terminal when i hit run in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't want any shortcuts, I tried "code runner" extension but its launches in the OUTPUT section and the cursor starts at the beginning of the text and I can't type anything

[image of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMSWp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I saw an answer in similar question, that's:

Install Code Runner from vscode extensions

Then Add the following line in settings.json :
"code-runner.preserveFocus": false

And it worked with me